# Tuples "cannot be marshalled in a foreign call" when trying to export a Haskell function to C

Tags: c, haskell

I'm trying to call Haskell from C using `Foreign.C.Types` in Haskell but it keeps showing this error in the compiler:

> ```
>   * Unacceptable argument type in foreign declaration:
>         `(CInt, CInt)' cannot be marshalled in a foreign call
>     * When checking declaration:
>         foreign export ccall "func_hs" func_hs :: (CInt, CInt) -> CInt
>    |
> 15 | foreign export ccall func_hs :: (CInt, CInt) -> CInt
>    | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> ```

The exact code compiled by GHCi version 8.6.3:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ForeignFunctionInterface #-}

module Func where

import Foreign.C.Types

verify_hp :: (CInt, CInt) -> CInt

verify_hp (hp, maxHp) = if hp < maxHp then hp + 10 else maxHp

func_hs :: (CInt, CInt) -> CInt

func_hs (hp, maxHp) = if verify_hp(hp,maxHp) == hp + 10 && hp < maxHp then hp + 10 else maxHp


foreign export ccall func_hs :: (CInt, CInt) -> CInt
```

Why is this occuring and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 4):

You're not supposed to uncurry the arguments of exported functions. Use this in place of your `func_hs` and it will work fine:

```hs
func_hs :: CInt -> CInt -> CInt

func_hs hp maxHp = if verify_hp(hp,maxHp) == hp + 10 && hp < maxHp then hp + 10 else maxHp


foreign export ccall func_hs :: CInt -> CInt -> CInt
```

In the working version, the C signature of `func_hs` looks something like this:

```c
int func_hs(int hp, int maxHp);
```

In your original, non-working version, it would have to look something like this:

```c
int func_hs(tuple<int, int> hp_and_maxHp); // not valid C!
```